How to pass cell value as the Query value for a query utilizing Power Query in ADF
My long winded question to a boiled down one liner in bold.
CORE QUESTION: How/can I pass in a value in a cell(LKP_Value) as part of my next query's let statement?
Background Details:
I have isolated 1 cell's value from and it's named LKP_Value
The LKP_Value is just a series of Table.AddColumn functions which I know work because I made them in power query then just copied the values into a lkp table.
The LKP_VALUE is a series of adding columns by their range(example below):
" Table.AddColumn(Source, "SURVEY_COLUMN_1", each Text.Middle([Column1], 0,2), type text) ,
#"Inserted text range 1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted text range", "SURVEY_COLUMN_2", each Text.Middle([Column1], 3,2), type text) .....in #"Removed columns""

I can add the entire let statement as the cell value for the LKP_VALUE, I can put any value necessary into my LKP_TABLE to get this to be dynamic.
I thought something like this would work:
let Source = #"SOURCE_LKP_FILE",
Source2 = #"SURVEY_PARAMS",
  #"Inserted text range" = #"LKP_Value" 
  in #"Removed columns"

What I want it to look like if the LKP_Value was resolved:
let Source = #"SOURCE_LKP_FILE",
Source2 = #"SURVEY_PARAMS",
#"Inserted text range" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "SURVEY_COLUMN_1", each Text.Middle([Column1], 0,2), type text) ,
#"Inserted text range 1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted text range", "SURVEY_COLUMN_2", each Text.Middle([Column1], 3,4), type text) ,
#"Removed columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted text range 1", {"Column1"}) in #"Removed columns"


Could you add more details? pipeline image/ code

So the way you're understanding Type in Code in General is wrong.
Your LKP_Value is a text value.
You cannot pass it as a code snippet because it's part of your data.
You can build custom functions by using the following syntax in a New Query
You can store variable before hand and call them in your custom function too to give more flexibility and shape it according to your data
customFunction = (parameter as type) =>
let
 Source = parameter,
 doThingsWParameter = Do.Things(parameter,1)
in
 doThingsWParameter

then call customFunction([Column1]) in your main query
